# Can we say anything if $f(a) = f'(a) = -f''(a)$ or $-f(a) = f'(a) = f''(a)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

Given a continuous and twice differentiable function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$,

1. can we say anything if $\exists a \in \mathbb R$ s.t.

$$-f(a) = f'(a) = f''(a)?$$

2. How about if

$$f(a) = f'(a) = -f''(a)?$$

I'm guessing $f = 0$ is a possible function. Any other possible functions?

---

3. Also, what exactly does it mean to say to that

$$f'(a) = -f''(a)$$ or $$f'(a) = f''(a)$$ anyway? The slope at $a$ is $\pm$ the concavity at $a$ sooooo...?

Comment: $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$, $x\not=0$ and $f(0)=0$ has $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ $\forall$ $n$.

Comment: $f(x)=be^x$ gives us $-be^a=be^a=be^a$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Thanks ^-^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

First, let's say $a=0$ (or let $g(x)=f(x-a)$). When you got some family of solutions ($be^x-2b$, in your case), it's often good idea to try writing parameter as function of x, $f(x) = b(x)e^x - 2b(x)$, then $2b(0)-b(0)e^0 = b(0)e^0+b'(0)e^0 = b(0)e^0 + 2b'(0)e^0+b''(0)e^0$. Thus we have constraints $b'(0)=0, b''(0)=0$. Any $b(x)$ satisfying these constrains (say, $x^3$) will give you some solution.

2.

The same trick with solution $be^x-bx^2$ will give you all possible functions as well.

3.

Geometry (or physics, when you interpret first derivative as "speed" and second derivative as "acceleration") stops being useful somewhere around here. It means that function $f$ isn't just any function, but satisfies some (rather weak) formal constraint. No more, no less.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your first question: $f(x)=\pm (x-a)^k$, with $k\ge 2$ is another possible function.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/526717)

Comment: @G-man. The first question of the OP is clearly: Any other possible functions? So, ok I admit that this a partial answer. But far from being a request for clarification or critique...